# How to use Telephony. It's @hide

Tags: android

I want to do sth with SMS-Conversation. So I get it from URI `content://mms-sms/conversations`. But the problem comes out. That is though I can get columns from the cursor, but it's too dangerous. Because the columns vary from different device. So I want to use `Provider`. Having read the source code I find the class `Telephony` that can help me. But I cant use it. It's @hide!!  So is there any way that I can use it?